# Accesing function concurrently by creating two structure object

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct
{
    int ab;
    char bc[10];
}acc1;

typedef struct
{
   char p[10];
   acc1 *p1;
}acc2;

acc2 a1[2];

main()
{
    fun(&a1[0]);//these two function may be called simultaneously or proceduraly(in my program) 
    fun(&a1[1]); //
}

fun(acc2 *abc)
{
    abc->ab=12;
    fun1();
    fun2();
}
```

it is a sample code,here in main program i am calling fun() and i passed array of structure a1[0],fun() takes some time to return back,concurrently fun() with a[1] goes to the function definition,now the both using fun(),i want to create 
two object by using structure such that first fun() call use first object and second will use second object.

the problem is that suppose fun() passed 5000(address of a1[0]) and in function definition it recieved 5000 in pointer *abc but while function is running another function call will overide 5000 to 6000(a1[1])......

so i want create two object such that each function call will use its own object.

Comment: The function operates on its input variables, so what's the issue?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth yes but when both input function come simulatenously then abc variable will be overide..